# Tight coupling example not making sense

Tags: java

```
public class TightlyCoupledClient{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TightlyCoupledServer server = new TightlyCoupledServer();
        server.x=5; //should use a setter method
        System.out.println("Value of x: " + server.x);

        }
}

class TightlyCoupledServer {
    public int x = 0;
}
```

In "SCJP exam for J2SE 5 Platform" in states that if both a and b use each other, they are tightly coupled. It the uses the above example. But TightlyCoupledServer dosent seem as though it uses TightlyCoupledClient. How have i got this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These class are mutually dependent, but in a rather subtle way.

Clearly, `TightlyCoupledClient` depends directly on `TightlyCoupledServer`. It's right there in the source code.

In what sense is `TightlyCoupledServer` dependent on `TightlyCoupledClient`? Well, the server class has a public field, and presumably it relies on its clients -- all of them, not just `TightlyCoupledClient` -- to write to this field properly. Therefore, to verify the correctness of `TightlyCoupledServer` one has to examine the code for everything in the system that could possibly write to this field.

Consider writing a unit test for `TightlyCoupledServer`. We'd want to write something like:

```
assertEquals("x should be 5", 5, x);
```

For this assertion to be true, the code in `TightlyCoupledClient` must be correct and must have been run prior to this assertion. And there's your dependency.

Comment: So if class a has a public variable, and class a is instantiated by class b, a and b are tightly coupled. Or does class b have to use class a's public variable for them to be tightly coupled?

Comment: To me it's less about who instantiates whom, but if there are non-final public fields involved, that's an indication of tight coupling among users of that field. If the field's type changes, potentially code all over the system needs to change. If class b modifies a's field in a different way, that can cause code elsewhere in the system (in class a or any other classes that use the field) to break. That's what tight coupling means to me.

Comment: Right, because if class a had a method that used its public variable in some way, and because that variable can be changed outside the class, class a is dependent on all other classes for itself being able to run properly. Its reliant on all other class, its thus tightly coupled.

Answer (score 1):

Mutual dependency is only one case of when coupling is considered tight. Another case of tight coupling is the so-called *content coupling*, [which occurs when one module modifies or relies on the internal workings of another module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). Knowledge of the class name is considered part of inner workings of the `TightlyCoupledServer` module; so is the knowledge of its member variables.

Adding an interface and programming to it would decrease coupling. Injecting the code with an instance of `TightlyCoupledServer` that implements an interface would further reduce coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Tight coupling in simple words means, one class is directly dependent on other.
So, if modifications happen in one, you will have to test functionality of both class for any behavior mismatch.

Here TightlyCoupledClient is directly dependent on TightlyCoupledServer. So, if you modify something like constructor for TightlyCoupledServer, you will have to test the changes appropriately for  TightlyCoupledClient.